# working with STL DS when it's elements are objects

Tags: c++, stl, containers, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

if I wanna use vector and each element is a different class (vector <Product*>productList)
in that case, how do I create copy c'tor and assignment operator since each element in the vector is an object.
I tried it the "usual" way, but it gave me an error E0312 and wrote to me that the conversion does not exist, I'm struggling to understand what these errors mean..

also in general, when i have STL array (vector,List ...) and its elements are classes *, how do I work
 with it ?, Is it similar to the regular array and i need to take care of the deep copy, c'tor, assignment operator, etc... or it does it automatically even when the elements are dynamic classes ?

thank you !

as suggested i changed from vector <Product*>productList to vector std::shared_ptr<Product>productList

```
class allProduct
{
    vector <std::shared_ptr<Product>>productList;
    int numOfProducts;
}


allProduct::allProduct(const allProduct& other)
{
    vector <std::shared_ptr<Product>>NewproductList;

    typename vector <std::shared_ptr<Product>>::iterator it = other.productList.begin();
    for (; it != other.productList.end(); it++)
    {
        NewproductList.begin() = other.productList.begin();
    }    
}
allProduct& allProduct::operator=(const allProduct& other)
{
    numOfProducts = other.numOfProducts;
    typename vector <std::shared_ptr<Product>>::iterator it = other.productList.begin();
    for (;it !=(other.productList.end());it++)
    {
        addProduct(other.productList.begin());
        other.productList.begin()++;
    }
    return *this;
        
}
void allProduct::addProduct(Product* pro)
{
    numOfProducts++;
    this->productList.push_back(pro);
}
```

[those are the errors im getting- E0312,E0413](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX9fz.png)

Comment: you can copy a vector like this `productList = other.productList;` if this does not work there is a problem in code you didnt post. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Unless you are dealing with a polymorphic type, `vector <Product*>productList` should be `vector <Product>productList` so you are dealing with objects instead of pointers.  If it is polymorphic, then you should use a `vector <std::unique_ptr<Product>>productList` or a `vector <std::shared_ptr<Product>>productList`

Comment: Boost contains a set of containers that deal with pointers.  See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: Yes it is a polymorphic, each element is a pointer to a different object that each one on these objects is derived class of Product.  in this case, should I implement all the operators as well ?    if so, why it gives me an error while writing "other.productList.end():

Comment: do you want to copy the pointers or the objects? What is the error you get? Please include it in the question